# Leading zeros on JQuery Countdown Clock plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a JQuery [Countdown Clock plugin from here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

Unfortunately I need to have leading 0 where there are single digits. For example 1:1:22 should display as 01:01:22.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I got this working using the 'Layout' mode.

http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html

My code now looks like this...

```
        $j('#Countdown').countdown({
            until: until,
            layout: '<div class="countdown_section">' +
                 '<div><span class="digits">{dnn}</span><br/>Days</div>' +
                 '<div><span class="digits">{hnn}</span><br/>Hours</div>' +
                 '<div><span class="digits">{mnn}</span><br/>Minutes</div>' +
                 '<div><span class="digits">{snn}</span><br/>Seconds</div></div>',
            serverTime: since,
            onExpiry: function(){
                render_expire();
            }
        });
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

There was a **padZeroes** option added in version 2.0.0:
http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#padZeroes

example:

```
$("#foo").countdown({
    until: new Date(2014, 11-1, 14),
    padZeroes: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I added an issue to Countdown project to make new ["leading zeros" option](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/9400)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get that layout mode trick working, so I used this:

http://www.fundp.ac.be/sciences/chimie/javas/js_format.html

and spliced the code into the _showFull method in the countdown js file.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the "formats 1" section. The "Compact" format shows the leading zeros.

their example:

```
$('#compact').countdown({until: liftoffTime, compact: true, 
description: ''});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format easily using this method:

```
           $('#countdown').countdown({
                until: thedatetime_youwant,
                description: '',
                layout: '{hn}:{mnn}',
            });
```

This example does hours (single digit where possible) and minutes (2 digits always).